# Dead letter log store

Tags: software-development, logs

We operate on numerous aws sqs queues. As you are aware there are certain scenario's where these messages get dead lettered or marked as not processable.

Since we would like to store, display and possibly delete this information (what was dead lettered and the reason it was dead lettered).

Current options:

`Database` - eg. Postgres, mysql

**pros**:

- quick retrieval,
- easy to update
- well known.

**cons**:

- manually need to archive old information.
- expensive

`S3` - using something like iceberg or Hadoop

**pros**:

- cheap,
- automatically archives data

**cons**:

- unsure of performance

`CloudWatch or elk`

**pros**

- cheap
- easy to implement

**cons**

- performance is a question
- editing is a problem

from this list I am already leaning towards a database, however we haven't implemented any solutions yet. Tips research input is would be very welcome.